# Using Python decorators with data from a global variable

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I wrote a bit of code that works, but I'm not happy with the style, so maye you could help me with it. Wrapper function loops over a global variable and uses some of this data as arguments, so when I call a function, it has a different set of arguments than when it's defined. Here's the code sample:

```
from functools import wraps

global elems
elems = [('a','b')]

def onEachInList(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        results = [func(a, b, *args, **kwargs) for a, b in elems]
        return 'done'
   return wrapper

@onEachInList
def func_1(a, b, c):
    print(f'{a}{b}{c}')

@onEachInList
def func_2(a, b):
    print(f'{a}{b}')
```

Now when I use the functions, I just call

```
>>> func_1(c)
abc
'done'
>>> func_2()
ab
'done'
```

It works, but is that correct? If not, how should I write this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do accomplish? What are `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: In the real code I'm concurrently (with concurrent.futures) pulling or searching (c is the searched phrase) multiple git repos. a is the repo, b is it's name (mostly for debugging purposes)